# How do I use a method in a different class from a different file?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, inheritance

I have a class file where I wish to generate some test data from different class files by i.e. call a method.  Now my generatetestdata class file inherits the launching part of the application i.e. open browser, login, do things and then log out.  This applies to all my scripts : TestBase its called.  In my generatetestdata, I have created a method to simply generate multiple vehicles method name MultipleAddVehicle(); from another class but it gives me an error does not exist in its current context.  Where am I going wrong?  I have included the code where all my scripts inherit the launching of the application and teardown, the generatetestdata where the problem lies, and the method MultipleAddVehicle(); code

This is the launch script class file where all my class files inherit the launch.

```
public class TestBase
    {

        public IWebDriver driver;
        public clsCommon objCommon;
        public UserSetttingsRep _userSetRepo;
        public VechRep _vechRep;
        //public TC04_VehicleMgt childclassinstance;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void BaseTestInit()
        {
            // create chrome driver
            driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            // create class for commonly used components / functions
            objCommon = new clsCommon(driver);
            _userSetRepo = new UserSetttingsRep(driver);

            LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet();
            //GenerationTestData();
        }

        public void LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet()
        {
            // login the user
            objCommon.loginVT(driver);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.MoveToElement(_userSetRepo.userIcon).Click().Build().Perform(); //Hover on System 

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(UserSetttingsRep.InputOrganisationSelector)));

            objCommon.SendKeysAndClickTab(_userSetRepo.inputOrgansiation, "M-Powered Automation", driver);
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(UserSetttingsRep.InputOrganisationSelector)));
        }


        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanUp()
        {
            driver.Quit();
            objCommon.ValidateResult();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test method MultipleAddVehicle(); I am trying to run.

```
public void MultipleAddVehicle()
        {
            // loginVT();//Login to site
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.MoveToElement(_regRep.SystemIcon).Click().Build().Perform(); //Hower on System       }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
            _vechRep.VehicleMgmtLink.Click();
            (_vechRep.fleetDropDownMenu, "Fleetddd", driver);
            string[] array = { "AK12 OLX", "FN53 KTO", "OU03 TGX", "BF14 YDS" };
            // Loop with foreach and write colors with string interpolation.
            foreach (string VRN in array)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                _vechRep.AddNewVehicle.Click();
                _vechRep.VRNSearch.SendKeys(VRN);
                _vechRep.FindVehicle.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                _vechRep.VehicleTypeOption.SendKeys("Car");
                _vechRep.VehicleTypeOption.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                _vechRep.VehicleColor.SendKeys("Red");
                _vechRep.btnAddVehicle.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                try
                {
                    if (_vechRep.VehicleAddSuccessMsg.Displayed)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Vehicle is successfuly added");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Vehicle is NOT added");
                    Assert.Fail();
                }
            }
        }
```

And finally this is my generatetestdata where the MultipleAddVehicle(); fails:

```
[TestClass]
    public class GenerateTestData : TestBase
    {
        public HealthRep _healthRep;
        public UserRegRep _regRep;


        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _regRep = new UserRegRep(driver);
            _healthRep = new HealthRep(driver);

        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void AddMultipleVehiclesToApp()
        {
            MultipleAddVehicle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added that new class file to "using"?

Comment: It just goes gray using VTUnitTestProj.TC04_VehicleMgt;

Comment: Which class is `MultipleAddVehicle` in? Is it in `TestBase`?

Comment: No its in TC04_VehicleMgt.cs as a test method

Comment: Ok, so that's the file name, is the class name the same? Does the file have `public class TC04_VehicleMgt` near the top?

Comment: public class TC04_VehicleMgt...yes....actually its public class TC04_VehicleMgt : TestBase

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of your second class, and call the method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddMultipleVehiclesToApp()
{
    var vehicleMgt = new TC04_VehicleMgt();
    vehicleMgt.MultipleAddVehicle(); 
}
```

Or, if you want to use the instance variable:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddMultipleVehiclesToApp()
{
    this.childclassinstance = new TC04_VehicleMgt();
    this.childclassinstance.MultipleAddVehicle(); 
}
```

and uncomment this bit:

```
public TC04_VehicleMgt childclassinstance;
```

You may also need to pass `_vechRep` from one class to the other. If so,  consider setting it in a constructor.

Comment: But TC04_VehicleMgt(); is the actual class file name? i.e. TC04_VehicleMgt.cs